# Как нарисовать такую цепь треугольников с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, svg

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нарисовать такую цепь треугольников от края до края страницы с помощью CSS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Нарисовать в `svg` треугольник с отступом справа (или в вашем случае экспортировать из figma, но затем для отступа сделать шире)

```html
<svg width="124" height="62" viewBox="0 0 124 62" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M0,0 104,0 52,62 z" fill="#5cd4c6" />
</svg>
```

2) Поставить его фоновым изображением с повтором по горизонтали (не обязательно data-url, можно и обычной ссылкой)

```css
body{
  background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTI0IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjYyIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTI0IDYyIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPg0KCTxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLDAgMTA0LDAgNTIsNjIgeiIgZmlsbD0iIzVjZDRjNiIgLz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K) repeat-x left top;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Подскажите только, как у второго способа менять размер?

Comment: @NikitaR. , это не 2 способа, это пошаговая инструкция. Т.е. в свойстве background содержимое шага 1. Код из первого шага можно сохранить в файл формата `svg` и для нужного элемента прописать `background: url(file.svg) repeat-x` . Размер удобнее всего вам будет регулировать через `background-size`